# Dynamically forming query in JQGrid

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jqgrid

I would like to dynamically query data from a table and display it based on user logged in. I have 2 files : one is the index.php that catches the user's admin products like :

```
$currentUser = CurrentUser::getInstance();
$UserID = $currentUser->getId();

//Get admin products
$que1 = mysql_query("SELECT productid from admin_levels WHERE level>1 AND userid=$UserID ORDER BY productid");
$op1="";

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_row($que1)){
    foreach($row1 as $cell1){
        $op1.=$cell1.",";
    }
}

$temp1=strlen($op1)-1;
$op1=substr($op1,0,$temp1);
//op1 contains admin products for sql command
$_SESSION['w1']=$op1;
```

The op1 string contains something similar to this:

```
16,17,20,114,125
```

Now i want to add it in my jqgrid query:

```
//Get admin products
$y1=$_SESSION['w1'];
$opt1="WHERE issues.productid in (".$y1.")";

//Create query
$grid->SelectCommand = 'SELECT CONCAT(issues.type,"0",issues.kbid) as KBID,issues.issuesummary as Summary,products.productname as Product,issue_priorities.description as Priority,date_format(issues.createddate, "%d/%m/%Y") as Reported,date_format(issues.lastupdated, "%d/%m/%Y") as Updated,issue_status.statusdescription as Status,issue_resolutions.resdescription as Resolution,users.logon as Assigned FROM issues
    INNER JOIN issue_priorities ON issue_priorities.VALUE = issues.PRIORITY - 1 
    INNER JOIN issue_resolutions ON issue_resolutions.RESID = issues.RESOLUTION 
    INNER JOIN users ON users.ID = issues.ASSIGNEDUSERID
    INNER JOIN products ON products.PRODUCTID = issues.PRODUCTID
    INNER JOIN issue_status ON issue_status.STATUSID = issues.STATUS'
    .$opt1;
```

On echoing the sql command i get this:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'issues.productid in (16,17,20,114,125) LIMIT 0, 0' at line 6
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: probably you need just add space before `WHERE`? The current code can produce something like `...INNER JOIN issue_status ON issue_status.STATUSID = issues.STATUSWHERE issues.productid in (16,17,20,114,125) LIMIT 0, 0`

Comment: oleg, the space was added when making the question but in actual there is a space. coding cracker i do not understand what u mean.

Comment: I don't use MySQL myself. I use SQL Server instead. In case of the same problem with SQL Server I would SQL Server Profile to get the trace all SQL statements. Then I would analyse the *really executed* SQL statement and would execute it separately. After understanding the problem and fixing it I would adjust my main code so that it would generated the fixed SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax error comes may be to single quote try

```
 $grid->SelectCommand = "your query".$opt1;
```

instead of

```
$grid->SelectCommand = 'your query'.$opt1;
```

Comment: and var surrounded with single quote : $opt1="WHERE issues.productid in ('".$y1."')";